# How to leave a parameter empty in giter8

Tags: sbt, giter8

Currently in g8 you create a project by giving a default value to a parameter:

```
g8 foundweekends/giter8 --name=template-test
```

What if you want to leave that parameter empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I din't find a way to add an empty parameter. However, for me it worked to just add a single space character for those parameters that I wanted to be "empty".

```
g8 foundweekends/giter8 --name=' '
```